# How to read and edit system xml files of android 12+?

Tags: files, text-editor, html, editing, android-12

On previous android versions, I can easily read and edit system XML files using a text editor but XML files from android 12 cannot be read properly and they looks like random symbols. For example, I pulled `wallpaper_info.xml` from /data partition and text editors can't open the file properly.

Comment: Just a guess - they might be compressed to save space, or encrypted to prevent people from exploiting it.

Comment: Another possibility is that the XML files are now in binary xml format like the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in each APK.

Comment: I can read few strings though. So they aren't fully encrypted and compressed.

Comment: After checking [the source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/wallpaper/WallpaperManagerService.java;l=3137;drc=518bc8ac7099e83ade1129184a9f53dcc3f55d10), looks like @Robert is correct. `wallpaper_info.xml` is now stored using a serializer. You can open it with Hex Editor to read the value in bytes, but I can't recommend editing serialized output manually.